# Can i store a cursor.fetchone() in a variable

Tags: python

Hell guys just jumped in to python and i'm having a hard time figuring this out

I have 2 queries . . **`query1`** and **`query2`** now how can i tell
**`row = cursor.fetchone()`** that i am refering to **`query1`** and not **`query2`**

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
query1  = cursor.execute("select * FROM spam")
query2  = cursor.execute("select * FROM eggs")
row = cursor.fetchone ()
```

thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once you perform the second query, the results from the first are gone.  (The return value of `execute` isn't useful.)  The correct way to work with two queries simultaneously is to have two cursors:

```
cursor1 = conn.cursor()
cursor2 = conn.cursor()
cursor1.execute("select * FROM spam")
cursor2.execute("select * FROM eggs")
cursor1.fetchone() #first result from query 1
cursor2.fetchone() #first result from query 2
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't. The return value from `cursor.execute` is meaningless. Per [PEP 249](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/):

```
.execute(operation[,parameters]) 

        Prepare and execute a database operation (query or
        command)...

        [...]

        Return values are not defined.
```

Comment: on large queries how do you do it?? your way??

Comment: Sorry, left that out. If you need to run multiple queries at once, you need to create a separate cursor for each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it the way you're trying to. Do something like this instead:

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute("select * FROM spam")
results1 = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("select * FROM eggs")

if results1 is not None and len(results1) > 0:
    print "First row from query1: ", results1[0]

row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    print "First row from query2: ", row
```

Comment: yes thankyou, but this is good only if your queries are small, what if you have a ton of queries to differantiate?? i'm thinking of the OOP approach.